# Cropping an image array

Tags: c, arrays, image, int, crop

I've tried to crop the image by creating a variable that is assigned by the user then subtracting that from the max value for the Width and Height of the image. 
 The problem is when I do the subtraction operator the result instead of HEIGHT - input = number, I get a weird number along the lines of -180000...

Here is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 1
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "functions.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#define HEIGHT 128
#define WIDTH 256
int image02[HEIGHT][WIDTH][3];
int image03[HEIGHT][WIDTH][3];
int x, y;

FILE*RED = NULL;
FILE*BLUE = NULL;
FILE*GREEN = NULL;
FILE*REDRead = NULL;
FILE*BLUERead = NULL;
FILE*GREENRead = NULL;
FILE*Write1 = NULL;
char cropans [30];
char red [30];
char green [30];
char blue [30];
char ppm [30];
char rotans [30];
int xcrop;
int ycrop;
int newheight;
int newwidth;

void main()
{

    printf("Type in filenames of the image files, including extensions\nThe program will exit if it cannot read any files\n");  //this is the UI//
    printf("Red channel data:  ");  
        scanf("%s", &red);
        REDRead = fopen(red, "r");  
        if (REDRead == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nCannot read red image data\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    printf("Green channel data:  ");
        scanf("%s", &green);
        GREENRead = fopen(green, "r");
        if (GREENRead == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nCannot read green image data\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    printf("Blue channel data:  ");
        scanf("%s", &blue); 
        BLUERead = fopen(blue, "r");
        if (BLUERead == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nCannot read blue image data\n");
            exit(0);
        }


    printf("\nNow type in the name of the file you want to create, with extension:\n");
        scanf("%s", &ppm);
    printf("\nWould you like to rotate a channel, or create an image without rotating any channels?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%s", &rotans);
    printf("\nWould you like to crop the image? (y/n)"); 
        scanf("%s", &cropans); 
        if (strcmp( cropans, "y") == 0)
            {
            printf("\ntype number of pixels to crop from x axis\n");
            scanf("%s", &xcrop);
            printf("\ntype number of pixels to crop from y axis\n");
            scanf("%s", &ycrop);            
            }
        else if(strcmp( cropans, "n") == 0);
        {
            printf("hi");
        }
    printf("got input correctly\n");


    //Zeroing the seperate arrays//
    for (y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++)                                  
    {
        for (x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++)                               
        {
            image02[y][x][0] = 0;                                   
            image02[y][x][1] = 0;                                   
            image02[y][x][2] = 0;                                   
        }
    }


    for (y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++)                                      
    {
        for (x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++)                                   
        {
            image03[y][x][0] = 0;                                   
            image03[y][x][1] = 0;                                   
            image03[y][x][2] = 0;                                   
        }
    }

    {
        int newwidth = (WIDTH - xcrop);
        int newheight = (HEIGHT - ycrop);
    }
    //printing to file part//
    //no rotation//

    if(strcmp( rotans, "n") == 0)
        {
            for (y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++)
                    {
                    fscanf(REDRead,"%d", &image03[y][x][0]);
                    fscanf(GREENRead, "%d",&image03[y][x][1]);
                    fscanf(BLUERead,"%d", &image03[y][x][2]);
                    }
            }   

        Write1 = fopen(ppm, "w");
        printf("got here 1");
        fprintf(Write1,"P3\n %d %d \n 255\n", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        for (y = 0; y<(HEIGHT); y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x<(WIDTH); x++)
                {
                fprintf(Write1,"%d %d %d ", image03[y][x][0], image03[y][x][1], image03[y][x][2]);
                }
        }
        printf("got here 1");
        }

else if (strcmp( rotans, "y") == 0)
    {
        for (y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++)
            {
                fscanf(REDRead,"%d", &image02[y][x][0]);
                fscanf(BLUERead,"%d", &image02[y][x][2]);
            }
        }

        for (y = HEIGHT; y>0; y--)
        {
            for (x = WIDTH; x>0; x--)
            {
                fscanf(GREENRead,"%d", &image02[y][x][1]);
            }
        }

        Write1 = fopen(ppm, "w");
        printf("got here 1");
        fprintf(Write1,"P3\n %d %d \n 255\n", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        for (y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++)
            {
            fprintf(Write1,"%d %d %d ", image02[y][x][0], image02[y + 11][x + 11][1], image02[y][x][2]);
            }
        }
        printf("got here 1");
    }

}
```

I'm pretty lost on this, any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You assigned to newly-created `newheight` and `newwidth`, which get created in the block where you declared/assigned them.  Because they go away when that block ends, you're left w/ your original versions, which never got assigned to!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `%s` for `xcrop` and `ycrop`.  You need to use `%d`.  In other words, this line

```
scanf("%s", &xcrop);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &xcrop);
```